# jQuery grid for asp.net with dynamic columns

Tags: jquery, asp.net

There are lots of different jquery grid plugins available but I either can't seem to find or can't work out how to fill one dynamically.  By this I mean to one grid I could be returning a dataset/json etc with 5 columns or one with just 2 and I want it to adjust accordingly.  All the ones I find require you to specify the columns in some way before assigning data but I can't do this as the data returned to the grid is completely random (as its to be used as a data preview for the user when selecting tables/fields).

Does anyone know of one that can handle dynamic columns or of one I can use that I can easily modify them each time accordingly?

Comment: I think most of the grid plugin like jQGrid expects array of column models. So you start think how to build those dynamically based on the need and assign that as data model to the grid.

Comment: Want to avoid doing this though, just want to apply a model.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The Infragistics jQuery Grid does have a feature for automatically generating columns. Here's a sample displaying this:

[igGrid Auto Column Generation](http://www.infragistics.com/products/jquery/sample/grid/auto-generate-columns)

Comment: That is exactly what I'm looking for, a grid that I can simply apply an array/model to and no messing about with HTML or column definitions.  Only problem now is convincing management for me to buy it.

Answer (score 0):

I'd suggest using something like [datatables](http://www.datatables.net/).  This one will allow you to build your grid as a normal html table and then apply the datatables plugin to it, this way you have control over how your table looks like first before turning it into a grid

Comment: Thats the point I want to simply apply data to a grid not mess around with actually creating all the HTML otherwise I might as well do this myself instead of using a plugin.